# How to attach IDA Window back to be part of the IDA main window

Tags: ida, windows

I accidently maximized the functions Window and now it is de attached from the main window:
[image]

How can I attach it back to be part of the main window? I tried to drag it but it doesn't work. Also re opening IDA didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

You can reattach your window by placing your mouse on the thin gray bar, as in this screenshot :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your screenshot, you can see a thin strip of gray between the title of the window (`Functions window`) and the column headers (e.g. `Function name`). If you hover your mouse in that gray area, it will expand and the title text (`Functions window`) will appear again, as in the following screenshot:

[image: mouseover on the gray area beneath the title]

Once that happens, hold down the left click button and move the window. You will see a number of icons appear around the edges, and in the center of the IDA window, as follows:

[image: after clicking/dragging the gray area]

Your first option is to ignore those icons, and drag the window into the area with the tabbed window names (e.g `IDA View-A`, `Pseudocode-A`, etc). The window will become an ordinary tab again. This is probably what you want.

Alternatively, you can drag your mouse onto one of the aforementioned icons to get a split-screen view. I recommend playing with them to get an intuitive feel for what the icons do, but here's a textual description:

- Leftmost/center-left icon : the current tab will now be split into two panes, with the one you dragged in on the left, and the active one on the right
- Rightmost/center-right icon: ditto, except the one you dragged will be on the right
- Topmost/center-top icon: the screen is split into two panes; the existing tabs will be in the bottom pane, and the current window will be in the top pane by itself
- Bottommost/center-bottom icon: ditto, except the one you dragged will be at the bottom